# SQL Server 2012 simple recovery mode - recovery options after crash

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-recovery, ldf

I have two questions about DB on SQL Server 2012 with recovery mode set to Simple (and DB itself holding mainly two huge tables with billions rows of data):

- in case of crash (or power failure etc.) can we recover something from .mdf and .ldf files and what data would we lost (e.g. everything from the last auto checkpoint was run?), or is the database backup the only way to restore (and so everything can be lost if there is no backup)?
- in Simple Recovery Mode - is the transaction file (.ldf) needed during recovery operation. What data would be lost if it's missing.

Currently our .mdf and .ldf are on the same mirrored disk, but we are hitting I/O subsystem bottleneck (repeating event 833 - 'I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete'), so we want to move our .ldf to SSD disk which has currently no redundancy. So we are trying to understand what would be lost in the worst case scenario (sudden failure causing .ldf to be unusable and leaving us only with .mdf file potentially with no recent database full backup).

Answer (score -1):

You will  have to wait because you have hues data in your database. it can take a lot of time.

Comment: We fully realize that recovery might take very long time. The main question is if the data won't be corrupted and which part of data might be missing.